# how to use vscode c++ debugger to pass arguments to program through gdb?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb

I want to debug `quickjs` `qjsc` which accepts arguments from `c++ argv`, 
and I also hope everyone can debug quickjs based my configuration for learning javascript engine.

But I can't pass arguments to program through gdb debugger in vscode

Here are my vscode `launch.json`

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "qjs-debug main.js",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/qjs-debug",
      "args": [
        "-I",
        "${workspaceFolder}/debugger/main.js"
      ],
      "stopAtEntry": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ],
      "logging": {"engineLogging": true},
      "preLaunchTask": "gcc build active file",
      "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
      "miDebuggerArgs": "--args"
    }
  ]
}
```

when I start debug, I saw argv only have a `/`

[image]

Some anwsers said `args` in `launch.json` will pass to gdb, you should use `--args` instead.

But I have tried. Nothing works :(

### My question is:

How I pass args to command cli based program?

Why argv is `/` from picture?

---

My repo is

https://github.com/iamwwc/quickjs-debugger

You can get all configuration from my github.

Comment: Everything is fine. You just read this incorrectly. Add watch `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`. [This](https://github.com/iamwwc/quickjs-debugger/blob/b8dd078f3a093819a431d55e6f60fc87efac9694/qjs.c#L278) form of main is used: `int main(int ac, char** av)` instead `int main(int ac, char* av[])` which confuses debugger a bit. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

Comment: @MarekR you are right, It's a vscode UI bug I think. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/688

Comment: No it is not a bug. When pointer to any type (but `char` or `wchar_t`), it is assumed it is pointer to single element. When equivalent argument of C array is seen, then this pointer debugger will tread as pointer to multiple values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not in VSCode launch configuration but in the way your program read the inputs, @Marek R said in the comments.

It is recommended to use `int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { body }` instead of `int main(int argc, char **argv) { body }` (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function)).